# Unable to write the SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with the following table structure and entries. 
I want to write a query that will give me name of the columns for a particular row whose row value is null corresponding to a particular user. 
Like for name = mayur  i want the output as 
"Company Gender Citizen" but not others because their value is NULL.

Note: 
1.OMIT the "Name, ID Password, Email" columns.
2. all the column name may change as the admin has the right to add or remove columns. 
[image]

Please help me writing the SQL query.

Comment: Getting the back the column _names_ strikes me as an odd request.  Are you sure you want that, or do you want the _values_ inside those columns?

Comment: I want to get the column name for a particular user which are not null except the Name, IS, Password, Email, Company,Gender and Citizen.

Comment: you may get help from this ................SELECT *
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema ='schema_name' AND table_name ='table_name';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Company IS NULL THEN 'Company, ' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN Gender IS NULL THEN 'Gender, ' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN Citizen IS NULL THEN 'Citizen, ' ELSE '' END
-- + ... -- add CASE statement for all other relevant columns
FROM Table_Name
WHERE Name = 'mayur'
```

You will need to clear the last comma created, but I think it is no big deal.

Comment: all the column name may change as the admin has the right to add or remove columns. I cannot hardcode the name of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just little modification in previous response

SQL SERVER version

```
DECLARE @query as varchar(max);
SET @query='select '+stuff((select '+'+'CASE WHEN ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] is null THEN '''+COLUMN_NAME+ ''' ELSE '''' END' from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'users' AND COLUMN_NAME not in ('Name', 'ID', 'Password', 'Email') for xml path('')),1,1,'')+' from users WHERE [name]=''mayur'' ';
execute(@query)
```

MySQL version

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('CASE WHEN `',`COLUMN_NAME`,'` is null THEN ''',COLUMN_NAME,''' ELSE '''' END ') ) into @casestmt
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='users';
set @query="select @casestmt from users WHERE name='mayur'";
PREPARE stmt1 from @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

This will generate same query which @Giorgos Altanis had suggested only difference is that column names will be automatically fetched defined for table.
If you dont want to create Proc then you can  execute all statement at once which will give you desired output

Comment: Can you please help me with the exact query in a format so that I can check along with an explanation.

Comment: And also it seems like a stored proc. A direct query or multiple queries will help me implementing it.

Comment: I have updated the query as per your requirement. For this I am creating dynamic query. Stuff part is used for creating Case statement which @Giorgos Altanis had suggested in his response. and it is then combined with your table to give you desired result.

Comment: I donot understand the query.. I cannot run it directly in sql. Can you please help me with the exact query .

Comment: My bad, I realized the database you are using is Mysql and my solution was for SQL server...Please see the edited version...I have added solution for MySql as well....for understanding the query... first select statement generates the case statement and later using prepare statement creating the query which will give you desired result...sorry for late response...let me know if you have any further doubt..